# Are ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta editor templates safe against CSRF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csrf, asp.net-mvc-4

Are pages generated by ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta templates safe against Cross-Site Request Forgery?

Specifically, are the "Edit" view and controller action generated by the "Controller with read/write actions and views, using EntityFramework" protected against CSRF?

Examining the HTML code generated by the Edit form, I can't see a hidden field or another way to implement an anti-forgery token.

Am I missing something or is the default example unsafe?

Comment: My understanding is that a template that generates vulnerable code is a security bug; I submitted a bug report on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/734975/code-generation-recipes-templates-must-not-generate-code-vulnerable-to-csrf-attacks).

Comment: I would drop the 4 from your title, also controller, they are editor templates, not controller templates. This is new to MVC 2, but not to MVC 3 or MVC 4.

Comment: I understand, but what I'm trying to find out is if the current Beta version has implemented protection against CSRF in its default templates or recipes. I already know that the older versions don't.

Comment: Beta hasn't changed from MVC 3 RTW.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to explicitly implement the anti forgery token.

In the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(...
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...
}
```

In the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
```

You can always create custom T4 templates to generate this for you, but no, the out-of-the-box templates do not do this by default.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the provided ASP.NET MVC templates generate code that is vulnerable to CSRF, and for providing sample code on how to correct this.

Comment: This doesn't work with IE. :( can u help me with IE ?